Spring Boot Cors Configuration. I get 401 on my react app
this is my first time using springboot and I'm facing an issue with the cors configuration.
I've tried many things but I always seem to get:
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:52700/greeting-javaconfig' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
Im on this error for a week or so, and I've played with the cors configuration files with many properties yet I cant seem to make it work
Ive created a CorsConfig.java file in my config folder with this following code:
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;



@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*") // Allow requests from any origin
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE") // Allowed HTTP methods
                .allowedHeaders("*"); // Allowed headers
    }

    @Bean
    CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");


        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return new CorsWebFilter(source);
    }
}

It looks standard to me and I saw many examples that use this more or less same format
And I also notice that i need cors filter from some examples so ive also added that to the project after noticing that without it it still doesnt work:
package com.example.config;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class CorsFilter implements WebFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST,                       DELETE, OPTIONS");
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

}

when testing this code with debugger and postman, I get a response and the breakpoint is going threw this filter function.
i also have basic auth, i dont know if it matters to the question but ill add my code anyway with the controller as well just in case i dont left any important information out.
SecurityConfig.java:
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.MapReactiveUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring()
                // Spring Security should completely ignore URLs starting with /resources/
                .requestMatchers("/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .hasRole("USER").and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
        http.cors().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User
                .withUsername("user1")
                .password("{noop}user1Pass")  // {noop} for plain text, consider a password encoder for production
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user);
    }

}

Basecontroller:
package com.example.controller;
import com.makalu.makaluapi.models.Greeting;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@RestController
public class BaseController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000/")
    @GetMapping("/greeting-javaconfig")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        System.out.println("==== get greeting ====");
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}

It was really frustrating trying to make it work, but it is an intresting and important topic non the less. I'll appreciate any information on this subject, thank you!
Also this is the code i use for the api call, ive tried this:
const url = 'http://localhost:52700/greeting-javaconfig';

    username = 'user1';
    password = 'user1Pass';

    const credentials = btoa(username + ':' + password);

    const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'text/html',
                'cache-control': 'no-cache'
            },
            // credentials: 'same-origin'
        };

    // @ts-ignore
    fetch(url, options).then(response => {
        console.log(response.body);
    })

for more context ive also run this curl request:
curl -v -u user1:user1Pass -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Origin: http://localhost:3004" -X GET http://localhost:52700/greeting-javaconfig

And got this output:
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:52700...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 52700 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user1'
> GET /greeting-javaconfig HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:52700
> Authorization: Basic dXNlcjE6dXNlcjFQYXNz
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
> Origin: http://localhost:3004
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 34
< Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2024 08:43:30 GMT
<

I dont know if it is important but ill add it anyway for more context.
I was expecting to get 200OK but I get 401 unauthorized in the client, but in the postmen i get 200OK and the return value.

Some days ago i had a similar issue, the browser tools console showed me an error of Cors CrossOrigin and i started looking at everything related with this. Some days later i realized that the problem was not on CORS, the problem was that the firewall was blocking the access from ports 8085 so the console showed the CORS error.
Check if you are accessing the right ports and theres no firewall blocking the access, here you can find a similar error, CORS can sometimes be really generic. I hope it helps you in anyway!

The combination of using credentials together with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is causing problems, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Please specify your known origins in your CORS configuration, i.e. http://localhost:3000 instead of asterisk.
